# Can anyone help identify this vine?

Tags: vines

This vine is located in northern Indiana and so far approximately 7 feet long. Surviving with minimal water only because we don't know what it is and if it's worth the attention. It appears to be very healthy and still branching off at the base. Brown stems dark green leaves

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Going by photos of vegetative growth and the leaves only, it appears to be "Oriental Bittersweet vine" (Celastrus orbiculatus) or it could also be a hybrid with the "American Bittersweet".  It is a very aggressive, invasive vine.  It is also known for its attractive orange/red fruits which are persistent in the winter and sometimes used ornamentally.

https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/shrub/oriental-bittersweet

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celastrus_orbiculatus

Comment: So sad that vigorous easy to grow plants are actually exotics that cause harm to the indigenous plants.  Beautiful plant.  I would prune the heck out of it, PRACTICE pruning  using this vine and constantly cutting off the flowers.  If that wasn't enough then I'd, gag, kill it.

Comment: Not sure this is avine (climber) looks more like a shrub or tree to me, unless that brown woody stem isn't a stem but a stick...

Comment: yes, bittersweet has both shrub like and vine like growth in different regions of the plant.  A vine that also branches low at the base as described.